# How is HTML structured, compared to WPF?

Tags: html, css, wpf

I'm getting more into learning HTML but i'm stuck not knowing nor understanding how it lays elements out. I've used WPF quite a lot, and know that this code here:

```
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Content="A"/>
    <Grid   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="200,0,0,0">
        <Button Content="B" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150"/>
        <Button Content="C" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Margin="0,150,0,0"      Width="200"/>
        <Button Content="D"                               Margin="200,150,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Will result in a UI looking something like:
[image]

But i have no idea how to replicate something like this in HTML, where A's width is constantly 200 (could be pixels or dp or a more standard unit for web design) but is latched to the left, B is latched to the top constantly 150 pixels, but both B and D are resized when the web browser/view is resized (as their horizontal alignment is stretch)

From what i've  learned online, HTML is structured similarly to a stack panel so I just don't get how you get that horizontally stretching behaviour

Comment: You have to keep in mind that HTML only provides page structure; CSS is the thing that adds styling. [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a very, very useful CSS tool that is used to replicate content exactly like this.

Comment: FYI, using margins is not how WPF layout are constructed

Comment: Why are margins not used to lay out controls in WPF? I use margins all the time to add offsets a control relative to its parent

Comment: margins for offsets = yes. margins for layout = no. if I need to make "B" 175 px high, I will need to makes changes in 3 places instead of 1, when I use Grid capabilities (RowDefinitions) to create layout

Comment: It was just an example, I'd usually use a grid with row/column splits

Comment: You realise there's a css grid, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, flexbox is the tool of choice for implementing such things:

```css
.a,
.b,
.c,
.d {
  outline: 1px solid white;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  /*  content div is now a flexbox */
  display: flex;
  /*  div is size of screen for demonstration */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sub-content {
  /*  set width to remaining width not taken up by .a */
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  /*  set height to 100% of parent height */
  height: 100%;
}

.sub-sub-content {
  display: flex;
  /*  set width to 100% of parent width */
  width: 100%;
  /*  set height to remaining height not taken up by .b */
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}


/*  b, c, and d grow but are b is constant height */

.b {
  flex: 1;
  height: 150px;
}

.c,
.d {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="sub-sub-content">
      <div class="c">C</div>
      <div class="d">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty cool :) I just found out about the "position" style, which you can set to absolute to take full control over the positioning, but I'm guessing that's bad practice

Comment: !REghZY It is no more bad practice than using chopsticks is; when used in the right situation, it is very useful. Absolute, relative, and fixed positioning remove their respective element from the document flow, so you can achieve overlapping, for example. However, it is very hard to achieve responsiveness with these positioned elements, so they are generally avoided for main page content.